# How do I implement a "loading screen"?

Tags: c, function, program-entry-point, time.h

Is there a way to call `loading_screen()` then clear the screen after three seconds and then go in with the programm?

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
    void loading_screen() {
        printf("\n*\t *\t *\t *\t *\t *\t *\t *\n* Welcome to your blah blah! *\n*\t *\t *\t *\t *\t *\t *\t *\n\n");
    }
    
    void starting_screen() {
        printf("1. add new recipe\n");
        printf("2. search for recipe\n");
        printf("3. delete recipe\n");
    }
    
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        loading_screen();
        starting_screen();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe, if your terminal/console accepts [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), you can do something...

Comment: ideone does not accept ANSI escape codes, but [something like this](https://ideone.com/tOuUyv)

Comment: What is the obstacle you are asking about? Waiting three seconds? Clearing the screen?